# JSP : MS SQL Server 2008 Insert Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, jsp, insert

I want to insert some session data in a database. I have one table called `SESSIONINFO` which has three columns, namely `SESSIONID (text), USERID(text), LASTACCESSTIME(smalldatetime)`. But when I am trying to insert values in the database, it returns Jasper exception.

JSP that I am using :

```
<html>
<head><title>Enter to database</title></head>
<body>
<table>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*;" %>
<% 

java.sql.Connection con;
java.sql.Statement s;
java.sql.ResultSet rs;
java.sql.PreparedStatement pst;

con=null;
s=null;
pst=null;
rs=null;

Date lastAccessTime = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());
//lastAccessTime = String("lastAccessTime");
String sessionID = session.getId();
String userName ="anni";

// Remember to change the next line with your own environment
String url= 
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/someDB";
String id= "testuser";
String pass = "testpasswd";
try{

Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);

}catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
cnfex.printStackTrace();
}

String sql = "insert into SESSIONINFO (SESSIONID, USERID, LASTACCESSTIME) values ('"+sessionID+"', '"+userName+"', '"+lastAccessTime"')";
try{
s = con.createStatement();
rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally{
if(rs!=null) rs.close();
if(s!=null) s.close();
if(con!=null) con.close();
}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Error -

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 38 in the jsp file: /pages/insertsql.jsp
Syntax error on token ""\')"", delete this token
35: cnfex.printStackTrace();
36: }
37: 
38: String sql = "insert into SESSIONINFO (SESSIONID, USERID, LASTACCESSTIME) values ('"+sessionID+"', '"+userName+"', '"+lastAccessTime"')";
39: try{
40: s = con.createStatement();
41: rs = s.executeQuery(sql);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:307)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:565)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:311)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

My select query works fine this way but seems there is something wrong in `INSERT` query syntax.

Kindly suggest. Thanks for all the help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add + after lastAccessTime.

```
String sql = "insert into SESSIONINFO (SESSIONID, USERID, LASTACCESSTIME) values ('"+sessionID+"', '"+userName+"', '"+lastAccessTime + "')";
```

by the way, it will still not work because you cannot just concatenate the Date object to your query. use PreparedStatement instead. you may check [using text input to search Access date column with between/and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656570/using-text-input-to-search-access-date-column-with-between-and/11656849#11656849) for sample usage of PreparedStatement.

Comment: your suggestion seems very valid; but if I use prepared statement logic `pstatement.setDate(3, lastAccessTime);` where `pstatement` is an PS object, m getting `The method setDate(int, Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Date)`

Comment: jay- It worked. Got away with the above error by importing java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date. thanks buddy !!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am wrong, but reading between the lines of your output it would appear that have an eroneous '/' in one of your variables? It appears to be placing / (and maybe quotes too) into the INSERT statement rather than the actual value you intended.

I've looked further, and I was on right track above, but I think it is a missing concatenate symbol as opposed to eroneous varible. You appear to be missing a + at the end.

```
"+lastAccessTime"')";
```

should be...

```
"+lastAccessTime+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String sql = "insert into SESSIONINFO (SESSIONID, USERID, LASTACCESSTIME) values (' " +sessionID + " ', ' " + userName + " ',' " + lastAccessTime+"')"
```